# What is the difference between construct validity and reliability?

Tags: dataset

I want to design a questionnaire and examine a new construct (variable) in my research with a five point scale from 1 to 5. How can I test whether the questionnaire satisfies the requirements of reliability and construct validity?

Comment: Reliability is purely about measurement precision (how much true score = measurement error-free variance is in your measured variable). Validity refers to whether an item/scale measures the attribute that you want to measure. Validity is much more complicated to assess since it is not just about random measurement error. It involves the question of whether the attribute or construct that you want to measure truly exists and whether variation in your item or scale reflects variation in the underlying construct. Construct validity is often assessed based on convergent and discriminant validity.

Comment: Campbell, D. T., & Fiske, D. W. (1959). Convergent and discriminant validation by the multitrait-multimethod matrix. Psychological Bulletin, 56, 81–105.
Cronbach, L. J., & Meehl, P. E. (1955). Construct validity in psychological tests. Psychological Bulletin, 52(4), 281-302.
Raykov, T., & Marcoulides, G. A. (2011). Introduction to psychometric theory. Routledge/Taylor & Francis Group.

Comment: Sir! you are a very nice teacher and editor. thanks !

Comment: You're very welcome.